# Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Area 51: What's the difference in a nutshell?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, area-51, stack-exchange

Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Area 51: What's the difference in a nutshell?
I've read the faq's and they all seem to be the same to me - Just Q & A on a variety of topics.

What's the difference in a nutshell?
If I have a software engineering question, which site is best for me to use?

Comment: "Just Q&A on a variety of topics." - Read the FAQs again. What part of the Area51 faq caused you to think it's a QA site and what part of stack overflow's faq caused you to _not_ think that you had answered your question?

Comment: Star Wars, Schindler's List, Samurai Cop... what's the difference? They're all just films on a variety of topics. If I want to see moving pictures, which one should I watch?

Comment: @KerrekSB - lol nice analogy

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Maybe *this* breakdown will help you understand the difference.

[**Stack Overflow**](http://stackoverflow.com) is a Q&A site for programmers. This is where you can ask and answer questions about *programming.*

Stack Overflow became so popular that users wanted to create *Stack Overflow-like* sites about *other* subjects. **Stack Exchange** is the name of the *network* of sites which users have created. You can see a list of the sites created [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

**Area 51** is the place where users can go to propose new ideas for Stack Exchange sites. Users post "example questions" as part of the proposal process, and there is [Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) for more extensive deliberations and discussions regarding the proposal as a whole. You can read more about the Area 51 process [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). And [here is a list](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) of the proposed sites.

Answer (score 10):

Q&A on a variety of topics is true of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange -- but remember Stack Exchange is the term for a) the engine and b) the network at

https://stackexchange.com/sites.

So when you say "Stack Exchange" that *includes* Stack Overflow. It's a network of Q&A sites.

As for Area 51, that's the place where we democratically vote to create new never-before-seen Q&A sites. The Area 51 FAQ is pretty clear on this point, I thought..

http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq